# INTU project after 24hours after-devcon-ends

Tags: project-intu, intu

I installed Intu manager on my computer a week ago and declare my Win10 computer as device and everything seems to be ok (can send a simple question and receive an answer)
One week later, i cannot find how to declare services credentials in Intu as the trial is over.
The doc in https://github.com/watson-intu/ says :" If you want to test Intu after the trial period, see **After DevCon ends**".=> but the link loops on itself : nothing more...
In INTU, ( following doc 6-vi of configuring Intu) : once choosen the org and the device, using the menu 'service', under the pane Services that appears, everything is empty .
- Is there somewhere a real doc "after devcon"  ?
- Do you know how and where to declare services credentials ?

thanks

Comment: why some downvote ?    
It's not a programming question but a real issue and IBM encourage to post questions for Intu on stackoverflow .  Where to post ?

Answer (score 1):

After your trial period. You can create bluemix account (not charge) and create your services (1-month free). Then you can edit the credentials via rg-gateway.mybluemix.net website. There is a Services section under Manage. There should see your services, and click pencil icon to edit based on your credentials that you can get from bluemix.